# Caching functions thread safe / deadlock safe for high traffic site?

Tags: .net, performance, caching, iis, thread-safety

Are the functions below a good practice for high traffice sites hitting these?  Is there any type of downfall with deadlocks or thread safe issues?

```
public static T GetInitializedTempCache<T>(string key, Func<T> getData, int minutes, bool skip = false)
{
    if (!skip)
    {
        var value = HttpRuntime.Cache[key];
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(T))
        {
            T data = getData();
            if (data != null && Config.Debugging.EnableCaching)
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(key, data, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes), TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
            }
            return data;
        }
        return (T)value;
    }
    else
    {
        return getData();
    }
}

public static void RemoveTempCacheContains(string key)
{
    var keys = new List<string>();

    var enumerator = HttpRuntime.Cache.GetEnumerator();

    // copy all keys that currently exist in Cache
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var cacheKey = (string)enumerator.Key;

        if (cacheKey.Contains(key))
        {
            keys.Add(cacheKey);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are looking at caching have a look at the https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly project, a "resilience and transient-fault-handling library". It may help you out in other areas of your website.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question for good practices for high traffic sites. Yes, caching long running IO request is a good practice, and making the caching mechanism generic is also a good practice. Two suggestion though, change `add` to `insert` since you most definitely will run into a race condition. `insert` will always insert the latest whereas add would always add the first. Second, since you mentioned high traffic, consider an async func alternative. Async, would allow the long running IO functions to not block the request threads.

To answer your question for downfalls. You aren't using any locks in this code, so you shouldn't run into any deadlocks. `getData()` I imagine doesn't have any locks either and is just doing some long running IO. `HttpRuntime.Cache` is also thread safe. So unless `getData()` is not thread safe or has locks, this should be fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19591255)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard How does this not answer his questions? I pointed out that there are no downsides to his code, as he asked. And I gave recommendations for high traffic sites, as he asked. If you can find another question for me to answer for him, I'm all ears.

Comment: What do you think about this? `https://pseudomuto.com/2012/02/efficient-thread-safe-caching-with-asp.net/`

Comment: @MikeFlynn He is treating retrieving from cache vs the database as a race condition. However, if you take that approach and you have 100,000 requests come in at the exact same time, then you effectively serialize the responses waiting for each request to verify it should get data from cache and not the database. Therefore if your DB request takes 10ms and cache takes 1ms, your last request will take 1ms for the first cache check, 12ms for the first lock, and 99,999 * 1ms for each subsequent lock; a 110.001s response time. I would use the datasource that is available at the time of the request.

Comment: Are you saying I should use a `lock` setup like he did or is that just irrelvant.

Comment: his code only guarantees that you source data from the database once and cache on every other request until it expires. The cost is that if requests do come in all at once and the cache does not exist, then all of the requests will become serial instead of parallel. I contest that you should never serialize your request unless there is an actual potential for the data to be different. Race conditions are only a concern if the outcomes are different. Getting the data from the database or cache should be the same. Worry about keeping them in sync and try to utilize the cache as much as possible.

Comment: "never serialize your request unless there is an actual potential for the data to be different.", doesnt make much sense.  Wouldnt you want to have data access via a cache if the data is the same for each request?  If the request is different then of course we shouldnt cache one set of data for all queued requests.

Comment: "Wouldnt you want to have data access via a cache if the data is the same for each request?". Yes, but what his code is doing is saying a bunch of identical requests come in at the exact same time and the cache key doesn't exist. So instead of all of those requests going against the DB and populating cache for future requests, as your code would do, he blocks all of the threads and lets one thread make a call to the DB and populate cache, and then lets one thread at a time check cache and return the response. He turns parallel requests into serial. Granted in memory cache should be very fast.

Comment: Yes I know that is exactly what he is doing, however is this an advantage or disadvantage.  I could very well do this but could there for a negative impact on my site by doing this?  I am afraid to go this route only because of unknowns I maybe ignorant about.

Comment: It depends on your web traffic. Based on the fact that you are using in memory cache over shared and are concerned with threads instead of services, then I would say there is a very low chance you will notice any difference. Both make use of a solid caching scheme and only diverge performance concerns for the smallest fraction of time. Both have advantages and disadvantages that would only present themselves at the highest of volumes. If you are reaching those volumes, you are probably looking to scale horizontally at that point and need to switch schemes any way.